# Need Help on SQL Query - incorporating AVG

Tags: sql-server

[Edit from @marcus-vinicius-pompeu: I rewrote the query for better identation. To bypass 'mostly code' constraint, I changed the original `group by` logic]

I am totally stuck while writing a query. Required output is attached. Query I have written is as below. it is working fine till column SL_30_Sec. How to add two columns ASA & AHT based on average values of each date

```
SELECT
  Date(t.call_date) as created_date,
  --
  Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Offered_Calls,
  Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered_Calls,
  --
  Concat(
    Round(
      (
        Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
        Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100
      ), 2
    ), '%'
  ) AS Success_Rate,
  --
  Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'three' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OB_Calls,
  Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'four'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OB_Calls_Received,
  Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'five'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Calls_ANS_in_30_Sec,
  --
  Concat(
    Round(
      (
        Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'five' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
        Sum(CASE WHEN t.table_name = 'one'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100
      ), 2
    ), '%'
  ) AS SL_30_Sec
FROM
  (
    SELECT call_date, 'one' AS table_name FROM table_1
    WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31 23:59' AND campaign_id = 'abc_inbound'
    -- -----
    UNION ALL
    -- -----
    SELECT call_date, 'two' AS table_name FROM table_1
    WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31 23:59' AND campaign_id = 'abc_inbound' AND term_reason IN('agent', 'caller')
    -- -----
    UNION ALL
    -- -----
    SELECT call_date, 'three' AS table_name FROM table_2
    WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31 23:59' AND campaign_id = 'xyz'
    -- -----
    UNION ALL
    -- -----
    SELECT call_date, 'four'  AS table_name FROM table_2
    WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31 23:59' AND campaign_id = 'xyz' AND term_reason IN('agent', 'caller')
    -- -----
    UNION ALL
    -- -----
    SELECT call_date, 'five' AS table_name FROM table_1
    WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31 23:59' AND campaign_id = 'abc_inbound' AND term_reason IN('agent', 'caller', 'ABANDON') AND queue_seconds <= 30
  ) t
GROUP BY Date(t.call_date)
```

Required Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, given the dataset...

- Table_1 = date of offered calls
- Table_2 = date of answered calls
- Table_3 = date of outbound calls
- Table_4 = date of offered outbound calls
- Table_5 = date of answered outbound calls in less than 30 seconds

To compute:

- ASA - you have to have the time of `answer time` (you should have, since the data allows for filtering those answered in 30 seconds or below)
- AHT - you have to have `answer time` **and** `talk & wrap time`

For **not outbound calls** it seems we already have `answer time` from `table_1.queue_seconds`...

Links for definitions:

- https://www.genroe.com/resources/glossary/call-centre-definitions-and-glossary
- https://www.callcentrehelper.com/how-to-measure-average-handling-time-52403.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT ((SUM(ASA) +SUM(AHT))/count(*))
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY date
```

Comment: I think you missed the question.  There is no ASA nor AHT in the current sql query. So the question is more about how to derive these.

Comment: @donPablo, Ahmed asked how to add the ASA & AHT columns, hence this answer. Not sure if it's correct though, but that is where he gets the data...

Comment: Correct. at the moment, I am able to fetch the date using two quires. I'm looking for a way to use one query